# Swift Move file to Shared App Container reduces file size

Tags: swift

I am attempting to copy a file that is bundled with my app into the shared app container.  It seems that when I use the .write method it drastically reduces the file size and corrupts the file.  Am I doing something incorrectly in my write method?

```
let sharedContainerURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.com.sharedBasemap")!
let fileURL = sharedContainerURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("localLayer.tpk")
    var tpkFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("localLayer", ofType: "tpk")
    print(sizeForLocalFilePath(tpkFile!))    // returns 3694906
    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileURL!.path!) {

        do {
            try tpkFile!.write(fileURL!.path!)
            print("file saved: \(fileURL)")

    } catch {
    print("error saving file")
    }
    } else {
    print("file already exists at \(fileURL)")
    }
    print(sizeForLocalFilePath(fileURL!.path!))   // returns 102

func sizeForLocalFilePath(filePath:String) -> UInt64 {
    do {
        let fileAttributes = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(filePath)
        if let fileSize = fileAttributes[NSFileSize]  {
            return (fileSize as! NSNumber).unsignedLongLongValue
        } else {
            print("Failed to get a size attribute from path: \(filePath)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to get file attributes for local path: \(filePath) with error: \(error)")
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: You are writing the file *path* to the destination file, not the file contents.

Comment: There are copy/move methods in NSFileManager you could/should use instead

Comment: If I try just .write(fileURL!) I get the following: "Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL' to expected argument type 'String'"